# Google closure editor open source projects and plugins

Tags: google-closure

Anyone know where i could find good plugins for the [closure editor](http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2010/07/introducing-closure-library-editor.html).
So far i only found:

https://github.com/yinhm/google-closure-editor-image

and

http://github.com/shripadk/google-closure-image-plugin

Image, video, HTML edit, tables plugins would be useful. Another plugin that would be of interest is one that would let one toolbar edit multiple fields. (http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/6fd6d412406d40/113aca2e17b28d54)

The ideal solution would be a precompiled version of the editor which can be included directly in the page with some minor configuration (wishful thinking).

Thx!

Comment: Interesting question.  I've wondered about the feasibility of doing text highlighting via a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have second-hand knowledge that Google has an arsenal of tools and plugins for use with the Closure Library. They have not, however, released anything more than what you have mentioned here.

I have considered creating something of a rough IDE/toolkit of my own, but hold back with hopes that they will open up their tools to the public.

All I can say is good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

I know that my answer is late, but looks like google team is not going to provide these plugins. Here is their answer form google closure library https://github.com/google/closure-library/issues/591

another developers suggest:

> So, if you plan to use the Google Closure Editor in your web app,
>   you're going to need to write a few plugins.

http://www.philipwhitt.com/blog/2013/10/how-to-write-a-simple-google-closure-editor-plugin/9 
it looks like this sample does not support undo of image insert

I spent a day while compiled the library (official guide is out of date - when you follow instruction, closure compiler says that python script mentioned there is not needed anymore). For my project text editor from google closure library missed several plugins. Texteditor differs from gmail's text editor - at least  it is limited version. Alas, I ended up with using another text editor.